# Convert curl command to PHP cURL - kaaProject

Tags: php, command, php-curl, curl-commandline, kaa

```
    curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 \
-F 'notification={"applicationId":"32768","schemaId":"32771","topicId":"32768","type":"USER"};type=application/json' \
-F file=@notification.json \
'http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification'
```

I tried to convert it into PHP and ended like this:

```
    $notification = array("applicationId" =>"32768",
        "schemaId"=>"32771",
        "topicId"=>"32768",
        "type"=>"USER");
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Basic ZGV2dXNlcjpkZXZ1c2VyMTIz';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzeZR8KqAYJyI2jPL';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'notification='.json_encode($notification).'&file='.realpath('notification.json'));
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    print $content;
    curl_close($ch);
```

I don't know how to set parameter "notification" and 'file'. 
please give me  a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: We're here to help you when you get stuck trying to get code to work, not write code for you. You need to show some effort first.

Comment: my post edited, please help me @aynber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to try the following code:

```
    $notification = array("applicationId" =>"32768",
            "schemaId"=>"32771",
            "topicId"=>"32768",
            "type"=>"USER"
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "devuser:devuser123");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
                                            'notification' => json_encode($notification),
                                            'file' => '@' . 'notification.json'
                                         ));
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    print $content;
    curl_close($ch);
```

Basically this code the same thing as bash command you provided, but with one difference - it does not provide *Content-Type* for *notification* param.

Instead of

```
--------------------------5766b31cc6648aa7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="notification"
Content-Type: application/json

{"applicationId":"32768","schemaId":"32771","topicId":"32768","type":"USER"}
--------------------------5766b31cc6648aa7
```

it sends

```
--------------------------dd3a987c4561b96a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="notification"

{"applicationId":"32768","schemaId":"32771","topicId":"32768","type":"USER"}
--------------------------dd3a987c4561b96a
```

However, I think this still should work fine. If not, please get back to me and I will provide you a different script that won't be that nice and clear, but will work.

================ UPDATE 1 ====================

Here's ugly script that must work

```
function multipart_build_query($fields, $boundary){
  $retval = '';
  foreach($fields as $name => $v){
        $data = $v[0];
        $filename = (isset($v[1])) ? '; filename="' . $v[1] . '"' : '';
        $type = (isset($v[2])) ? 'Content-Type: ' . $v[2] . "\n" : '';

        $retval .=  "--$boundary\n" .
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$name\"$filename\n$type\n" .
                "$data\n";
  }
  $retval .= "--$boundary--\n";
  return $retval;
}


    $notification = array("applicationId" =>"32768",
        "schemaId"=>"32771",
        "topicId"=>"32768",
        "type"=>"USER");

    $post_data = array(
        'notification' =>       array(
                                        json_encode($notification),
                                        null,
                                        'application/json'
                                ),
        'file' =>               array(
                                        file_get_contents('notification.json'),
                                        'notification.json',
                                        'application/octet-stream'
                                )
    );

    $boundary = md5(time() . mt_rand(1, 65536));


    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $boundary;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "devuser:devuser123");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, multipart_build_query($post_data, $boundary));
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    print $content;
    curl_close($ch);
```

----- UPDATE 2: Raw request added -----

```
POST /kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8088
Authorization: Basic ZGV2dXNlcjpkZXZ1c2VyMTIz
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 430
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------f03cb5aef819a622

--------------------------f03cb5aef819a622
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="notification"
Content-Type: application/json

{"applicationId":"32768","schemaId":"32771","topicId":"32768","type":"USER"}
--------------------------f03cb5aef819a622
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="notification.json"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

asdasdasdad

--------------------------f03cb5aef819a622--
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, I tried to run your code, but didn't work. I still get an error "Required request part 'notification' is not present". please help me with your differrent script, thanks again.

Comment: That's sad. I have updated my initial answer with the new script (its in the bottom). Check it out please.

Comment: hi @sota, you make my day :-D
your script will work fine after adding "\r" in your function
`function multipart_build_query($fields, $boundary){
 $retval = '';
 foreach($fields as $name => $v){
  $data = $v[0];
  $filename = (isset($v[1])) ? '; filename="' . $v[1] . '"' : '';
  $type = (isset($v[2])) ? 'Content-Type: ' . $v[2] . "\r\n" : '';

  $retval .=  "--$boundary\r\n" .
  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$name\"$filename\r\n$type\r\n"."$data\r\n";
 }
 $retval .= "--$boundary--\r\n";
 return $retval;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please put the raw data of the headers and body of the request you got with this php code ? 
I'm trying to do the same in Csharp.
Thank you

Comment: Hi! Posted raw request in my initial answer above.